# How to open & print a ebook in Daisy format on windows?

Tags: ebook

I've  downloaded this book: [ONE TWO THREE … INFINITY FACTS & SPECULATIONS OF SCIENCE (1947)](http://www.archive.org/details/onetwothreeinfin000923mbp) from archive.org which is zip archive of some set of files.

I'm on windows, I want to read it. How can I do that? Also, is it possible to print the book in this format or may be by converting into another format?

Comment: [Please read the FAQ](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Asking for product recommendations is off-topic. A simple Internet search for what you are looking for will return links to the software that will work. The FAQ on the site that you link to has links to the software you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AIMS](http://www.daisy.org/projects/amis/downloads/Setup-amis312-U.S.English.exe) to read Daisy ebooks on a PC, I'm not sure about its ability to print though...  Daisy was developed for people who have trouble reading print, so I'm not sure why you would want to use a daisy formatted book.  Try converting it.

**ADDITION**-- you might be able to copy all the text and past it into a word document, and print from there...

Comment: I don't prefer DAISY format. But  it seems that is the only format available for on archive.org